# Background color not working in a wrapper

Tags: html, css

for some reason I can't get my class blueback working (background remains desperately white), would you know why? Thanks
http://jsfiddle.net/wWLz4/

```
<div class="wrap980px blueback clear">
<div id="block-left">
<h2>dfd</h2>
</div> <!-- End DIV block-left -->

<div id="block-right">
jhjh
</div> <!-- End DIV bloack-right --> 
</div>  <!-- End DIV 980pxWrap -->
```

CSS

```
.wrap980px {
    margin: auto;
    width: 980px;
}

.blueback {
    background: #006DB8;
}

#block-left {
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 470px;
}
#block-right {
    float: right;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 470px;
}
.clear:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define height of wrap980px. For now its 0.
Example:

```
.wrap980px {
    margin: auto;
    width: 980px;
    height: 150px;

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wWLz4/1/

Answer (score 2):

Or, alternatively, add:

```
.wrap980px {
    overflow: hidden;
    ...
```

There are two floated elements within the container `<div>`, so it effectively has a height of zero. You can add a fixed height, as has already been suggested, or use the `oveflow: hidden;` trick.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
.wrap980px {
    margin: auto;
    width: 980px;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Or

```
.wrap980px {
        margin: auto;
        width: 980px;
        float:left;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
<div class="wrap980px blueback">
<div id="block-left">
<h2>dfd</h2>
</div> <!-- End DIV block-left -->

<div id="block-right clear">
jhjh
</div> <!-- End DIV bloack-right --> 
</div>
```

Or use alternativly:

```
.wrap980px{ overflow:hidden}
```